# Org-beamer export uses different footnote numbering style based on columns

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

Using org-beamer (Emacs 27.1, Org mode 9.3).

I have one slide that does not use columns, and one bullet point has a footnote. The footnote exports with an Arabic-numeral numbering style (1).

Another slide uses columns to position a graphic to the right, and one bullet point has a footnote. The footnote exports with a lowercase letter numbering style (a).

Two things are surprising:

1. Why does the numbering style change?
2. Why does the footnote number reset to *a*?

I suppose the logic is to maintain separate footnote indices for columnar vs non-columnar output... but... to me at least, it seems undesirable. Is there a way to disable this feature?

EDIT: Adding an example:

```
#+LANGUAGE:  en
#+OPTIONS:   H:2 num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:nil pri:nil tags:not-in-toc date:nil
#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport

#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+BEAMER_THEME: default
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_env(Env) %10BEAMER_act(Act) %4BEAMER_col(Col) %8BEAMER_opt(Opt)
#+PROPERTY: BEAMER_col_ALL 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.0 :ETC

* Section
** Example with bpm
*** Here, we already run into a /gotcha/.
    - We need to convert a beat value into ms.
    - I made an abstraction for that: =[tempo2ms]=.[fn:165f14b418382cff]

** Sync to barline
*** Left                                                              :BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_col: 0.5
    :END:
**** How?
     - Subtract small value.[fn:f0c72cc12c9e6ae]
*** Right                                                             :BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_col: 0.45
    :END:
    Here would be an image. Text should reproduce the issue.

* Footnotes

[fn:f0c72cc12c9e6ae] This footnote displays as "a".

[fn:165f14b418382cff] This footnote displays as "1".
```

Comment: HInt: post an example - it would make it much easier for somebody to cut-and-paste and try it out. Without it, one would have to invent their own example (with all the trial-and-error necessary to make sure that *their* example conforms to *your* specification). If you want to maximize your chances of getting an answer, then it's a good rule to follow.

Comment: Good point -- added.

Comment: If you produce the `.tex` file with `C-c C-e l B` and look at it, you'll see that both footnotes are produced by `\footnote{...}`, so Org mode cannot do anything about the final result. It's [Beamer](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) that's doing it, so that's where you have to go looking

Comment: @NickD Can you show the .tex file?

Comment: It would be easier for you to cut and paste the Org mode example that the OP posted and then try the export with `C-c C-e l B`. I did add a  [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xN6xKMfp) for it, but it will expire in a week.

Comment: @NickD Thanks! Much easier than installing emacs just to run a single file :)

Comment: @jamshark70 From the texnical perspective: you want to use `\footnote[frame]{This footnote displays as "a".}` instead of `\footnote{This footnote displays as "a".}` to get the same style for footnotes in columns.

Comment: Just a bit of background: beamer internally uses `minipages` to create columns and minipages do traditionally have a different footnote style in latex. You can for example try this example with the standard article class: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test\footnote{a}
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
test\footnote{a}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz is there a way to specify the footnote style in the preamble? If so, that can be directly used in the Org mode file. Getting `footnote[frame]{...}` *conditionally* would require changing code which the OP probably wants to avoid.

Comment: @NickD One could redefine the footnote macro to always use the `frame` variant: https://pastebin.com/HGJx66yH

Comment: Samcarter's pastebin does the job for me! That is way, way beyond my skill level. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Linux and have installed LaTeX from TeXLive, here's a way to package the [modification](https://pastebin.com/HGJx66yH) from @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's comment above to make it convenient to use from Org mode.

The steps are:

- create a file, `myframefootnote.sty`, in a directory where your TeX processor will be able to find it (in my case, I put it in `~/.texlive2021/texmf-config/tex/latex/personal` because that's the TeXLive distribution that I have installed on my Fedora 36 system - YMMV). Put into that file the redefinition of `\footnote` from @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's pastebin, i.e. the part between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, but *not* including those two `\makeat...` lines:

  ```
  \renewcommand<>{\footnote}[1][]{%
    \let\beamer@footnotetext=\@footnotetext%
    \let\beamer@mpfn=\@mpfn%
    \let\beamer@thempfn=\thempfn%
    \let\beamer@kvorig=\KV@errx%
    \let\beamer@xkvorig=\XKV@err
    \def\beamer@footarg{}%
    \def\KV@errx##1{\edef\beamer@footarg{\@tempa}}%
    \def\XKV@err##1{\edef\beamer@footarg{\XKV@tkey}}%
    \setkeys{beamerfootnote}{frame}% <- changed here from #1 to frame
    \let\KV@errx=\beamer@kvorig%
    \let\XKV@errx=\beamer@xkvorig
    \ifx\beamer@footarg\@empty%
      \def\beamer@next{\stepcounter\beamer@mpfn
        \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\beamer@thempfn}%
        \@footnotemark\beamer@footnotetext#2}%
    \else%
      \def\beamer@next{%
        \begingroup
          \csname c@\beamer@mpfn\endcsname\beamer@footarg\relax
          \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\beamer@thempfn}%
        \endgroup
        \@footnotemark\beamer@footnotetext#2}%
    \fi%
    \beamer@next}
  ```
- From a shell, check that your TeX processor can find the file. One way to do that is to run the command `kpsewhich myframefootnote.sty` if you have that command available. It should print out the path of the file. In my case, it says: `/home/<user>/.texlive2021/texmf-config/tex/latex/overarrows/overarrows.sty`.
- And then all you need to do is to add the following line to your Org mode file whenever you want to use this modified definition:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{myframefootnote}
```